# How to route all traffic through a peer behind NAT using Wireguard

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, mikrotik-routeros, wireguard

I have been trying to create a VPN tunnel, the topology is following:

```
Device A (Windows computer, behind NAT)
Device B (Debian 11 VPS with a public IP address)
Device C (MikroTik router that supports Wireguard, behind NAT)
```

I want to tunnel all the traffic on device A through the device C, and I am using the device B as a "bounce server". Here is the topology visualized:
[Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GWsS.png)

So far, I have been able to configure the VPN in a way that allows all of my devices to ping each other, but I can't route the traffic. Can please somebody explain how can I set the device B (VPS, "bounce server") to route all the traffic going from device A (Windows PC) through device C (MikroTik router)?

I want to connect to the VPN on device A (Windows PC), route all the traffic through device C (MikroTik) and appear to the outside internet to have the IP address of device C (MikroTik) - full tunnel.

The configuration files are following (PUBLIC-IP is the public IP of device B, the bounce server):

Device A (windows PC):

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.5.3/32
DNS = 1.1.1.1
PrivateKey = gO.....

[Peer]
# Name = bounce server
PublicKey = mLdpo....
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = PUBLIC-IP:54321
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Device B (VPS cloud, "bounce server"):

```
[Interface]
  # Name = bounce server
  Address = 10.10.5.1
  ListenPort = 54321
  PrivateKey = GD...
  Table = off

  [Peer]
  # Name = Device C, MikroTik router
  AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
  PublicKey = J7...
  # PersistentKeepalive = 300

  [Peer]
  # Name = Device A - Windows PC
  AllowedIPs = 10.10.5.3/24
  PublicKey = W7..
  # PersistentKeepalive = 300
```

Device C (MikroTik router):
Config export from MikroTik:

```
/interface wireguard
add listen-port=54321 name=wireguard1
/interface wireguard peers
add allowed-address=10.10.5.0/24 endpoint-address=PUBLIC-IP endpoint-port=54321 interface=wireguard1 \
    persistent-keepalive=25s public-key="mLd..."
```

Re-written into the classic configuration look:

```
[Interface]
      # Name = MikroTik
      Address = 10.10.5.2
      ListenPort = 54321
      PrivateKey = ...
    
      [Peer]
      # Name = Device B, VPS "bounce server"
      AllowedIPs = 10.10.5.0/24
      PublicKey = mLd...
      Endpoint = PUBLIC-IP:54321
      PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is your MikroTik router set up to masquerade 10.10.5.0/24 to the Internet? (ie something like this: https://help.mikrotik.com/docs/display/ROS/NAT#NAT-Masquerade)

Answer (score 2):

If you need internet for example from some VPN service

```
/interface wireguard add listen-port=51820 name=wireguard-inet private-key="xxx" comment="Internet through WireGuard commercial VPN provider"
/interface wireguard peers add allowed-address=0.0.0.0/0 endpoint-address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx endpoint-port=51820 interface=wireguard-inet persistent-keepalive=25m \
    preshared-key="xxx" public-key="xxx" comment="Internet through WireGuard commercial VPN provider"
/interface list member add interface=wireguard-inet list=WAN comment="Internet through WireGuard commercial VPN provider"
###
/ip address add address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32 interface=wireguard-inet comment="Internet through WireGuard commercial VPN provider"
/routing table add name=wireguard-wan fib comment="Internet through WireGuard commercial VPN provider"
/ip route add dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=wireguard-inet routing-table=wireguard-wan comment="Internet through WireGuard commercial VPN provider"
# xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 replace to your local network
/routing rule add action=lookup src-address=192.168.xxx.0/24 table=wireguard-wan comment="Internet through WireGuard commercial VPN provider"
# Add DNS from VPN service
/ip/dhcp-server/network/set dns-server=10.xxx.0.1 0
# Need to reconnect your device(PC, PHONE) for receive new DNS server from router
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It worked very well for me. I am able to reach internet through wireguard tunnel.